# How do I convert data from Laravel DB connection to GeoJSON

Tags: geojson, mapbox-gl-js, laravel-8

Currently making a project in Laravel that uses MapboxGLJS. I've currently got a database server that I'm connected to that contains comments which I need to convert to a GeoJSON FeatureCollection that includes the ID and the spacial data. I've seen an example of the code to do this which I'll provide below but when I try to use said code and try to use the `addSource` Mapbox method it comes back with `Error: Input data is not a valid GeoJSON object.`.

CommentController.php

```
...
public function all(){
      $comments = Comment::whereNotNull('user_id')->get();

        $mapFeatures = array();
        $mapFeatures['type'] = 'FeatureCollection';
        $mapFeatures['name'] = 'comments';
        $mapFeatures['crs'] = array(
            'type' => 'name',
            'properties' => array(
                'name' => 'urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84'
            ),
        );
        $mapFeatures['features'] = array();

        foreach ($comments as $comment) {

            $mapItem = array(
                'type' => 'Feature',
                'properties' => array(
                    'id' => $comment->id,
                ),
                'geometry' => $comment->location
            );

            array_push($mapFeatures['features'], $mapItem);
        }

        return json_encode($mapFeatures);
    }
...
```

Using Postman I collected the following from the api request:

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "name": "comments",
    "crs": {
        "type": "name",
        "properties": {
            "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"
        }
    },
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "id": 143
            },
            "geometry": "0101000020E6100000E17A14AE47E111C085EB51B81E054A40"
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

Running the data through https://geojsonlint.com/ it comes back with `Line 1: old-style crs member is not recommended, this object is equivalent to the default and should be removed`. Also stating that geometry was expected as an object but got a string which I assume is to do with the `crs` property not decoding the geometry correctly.

Is there a different `crs` that I need in order to get the geometry to be correctly decoded?
I unfortunately cannot change the data on the database to include a lat/long geometry as the current data is being used by another project which relies on it being in this format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discovered there is a package specifically to fix this issue available here:

https://github.com/mstaack/laravel-postgis

This just needs to be installed and referenced in the Controller that gets the coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

This:

> `"0101000020E6100000E17A14AE47E111C085EB51B81E054A40"`

is not a GeoJSON geometry. I'm not sure exactly what it is. It looks like PostGIS's native format (see [here](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsEWKT.html)) but I don't know what that is called or how to convert from it outside PostGIS.

A GeoJSON geometry would look like:

```
{
    "type": "LineString",
    "coordinates": [[...]]
}
```

If you have access to the PostGIS queries, you should use the [`ST_AsGeoJSON`](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsGeoJSON.html) function.

This has nothing to do with CRS's - the message is just telling you not to bother adding that `crs` property, assuming that your data is in EPSG:4326.